# Inconsistent Transpose

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table `A` has the following data:

```
+----------+-------+
| Supplier | buyer |
+----------+-------+
| A        |     1 |
| A        |     2 |
| B        |     3 |
| B        |     4 |
| B        |     5 |
+----------+-------+
```

My question is, can I transpose the second column so the resultant table will be like:

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| Supplier | buyer1 | buyer2 | buyer3 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A        |      1 |      2 |        |
| B        |      3 |      4 |      5 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Assuming the maximum number of buyers is known as three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a common table expression to give each buyer an order within the supplier, and then just do a regular case to put them in columns;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT supplier, buyer, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY supplier ORDER BY buyer) rn
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT supplier, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN buyer END) buyer1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN buyer END) buyer2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=3 THEN buyer END) buyer3
FROM cte
GROUP BY supplier;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48566/1).

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using PIVOT clause:

```
select *
from (
  select supplier, buyer, row_number() over (partition by supplier order by buyer) as seq
  from a
)
pivot (max(buyer) for seq in (1 as buyer1, 2 as buyer2, 3 as buyer3));
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d312/8).

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned that I am using oracle 10g. Pivot is available from 11g onwards.